# Don't Sleep Network Connection / VPN

Tags: macos, power-management

If I let my computer sleep my VPN connection seems to die. Mac shows it as still being up, but nothing over the VPN works until I reconnect and disconnect.

I am happy to have a my monitors sleep, but I want my network and VPN connection to stay active.

I'm running Yosemite with a wired connection. Anyone know how I might get this to happen? I'm open to using Caffeine or something like that, but with 3x 30 inch monitors my power bill will suck if I don't let them sleep (and turning them off is annoying because all my windows get rearranged).

Answer (score 4):

Just put your displays to sleep in the energy saver settings (like in the picture below) and it should work.

[image]

Please check the answer at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/62/why-do-vpn-connections-break-when-i-sleep-my-computer) for the reason why the VPN-connections breaks.

Answer (score 3):

You might try `caffeinate`. It's the terminal utility that the Caffeine app runs. Running it from the terminal allows you to have more options:

`caffeinate -ims` can prevent system + disk + idle sleeping while still allowing your screen to sleep

`man caffeinate`:

```
Available options:

 -d      Create an assertion to prevent the display from sleeping.

 -i      Create an assertion to prevent the system from idle sleeping.

 -m      Create an assertion to prevent the disk from idle sleeping.

 -s      Create an assertion to prevent the system from sleeping. This assertion is valid only when
         system is running on AC power.

 -u      Create an assertion to declare that user is active. If the display is off, this option turns
         the display on and prevents the display from going into idle sleep. If a timeout is not spec-
         ified with '-t' option, then this assertion is taken with a default of 5 second timeout.

 -t      Specifies the timeout value in seconds for which this assertion has to be valid. The asser-
         tion is dropped after the specified timeout. Timeout value is not used when an utility is
         invoked with this command.

 -w      Waits for the process with the specified pid to exit. Once the the process exits, the asser-
         tion is also released.  This option is ignored when used with utility option.
```

Answer (score -1):

There's another thread - and proposed solution that might apply: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5537854?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.